# Forward declaration of template

Tags: c++, templates

I don't like to use forward declarations as:

```
struct A;

struct B
{
   A* a;
}

// Implementation
```

I'm in habit to do something like:

```
struct B
{
   struct A* a;
}
```

But, I'have problems when I try to do it with template classes:

```
template<typename T>
struct A
{
    struct B<T>* _t;
};

template<typename T>
struct B
{
    T _t;
};
```

And the compiler says me:

```
test.cpp:4:12: error: 'B' is not a template
test.cpp:8:8: error: 'B' is not a template type
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: The real problem is this: Why don't you like forward declarations? They are the way to say "This is a valid type, even if you haven't seen the definition yet". Why would you want to avoid using them?

Answer (score 3):

Two steps.

Step 1: Define struct B before struct A

Step 2: Like forward declarations.

Answer (score 0):

double Vigneshwaren comment with code:
    template
    struct B
    {
        T _t;
    };

```
template<typename T>
struct A
{
    struct B<T>* _t;
};
```